# How to set a double x-axis label?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label

Here is where I am:

[image: my figure for now]

And I want to change it into this way:

[image: double x-axis label example]

The code is shown below:

```
D_max_ratio=numpy.divide(D_max_Nobs,D_max_1000)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.set_cmap('jet_r')
x_axis = ['100', '', '300',  '',"500","","700","","900","","1100","","1300","","1500"]
y_axis = ['10', '20', '30', '40',"50","60","70","80","90","100"]
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(D_max_ratio)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.set_xticks(numpy.arange(15))
ax.set_yticks(numpy.arange(10))
ax.set_xticklabels(x_axis)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_axis)
plt.xlabel('f/MHz')
plt.ylabel('$N_{obs}^{R}$')
cb=fig.colorbar(cax)
```

Comment: How about *not* doing that? The result will be confusing to the reader. Create second x axis instead with `twiny` function.

Comment: I am a assistant, that is the supervisor's requirement. So~~

Comment: So I don't think there is such an easy-to-use feature available. `imshow` may help you to achieve your goal with some hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is a parasite axis, as shown in this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html), which for your case is,

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Setup a host axis
host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

#Add twin y axis with offset from bottom and hide top axis
par = host.twiny()
offset = -30
new_fixed_axis = host.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
par.axis["bottom"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="bottom",
                                    axes=par,
                                    offset=(0, offset))
par.axis["top"].set_visible(False)

# Plot data and add main axis labels/limits
host.imshow(np.random.rand(128,1600))
host.set_xlabel("f/MHz")
host.set_xlim((0,1600))
plt.axis("tight")

#Set limits of parasite axis 
#(note this axis is not attached to 
# an actual plot so changes nothing)

par.set_xlabel("Ka")
par.set_xlim((0,15.71))

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

which looks like,

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It is exactly what i need. Additionally,can i remove axis at the top ?

Comment: Hi @Tang, I couldn't work this out yesterday (You need to call `par.axis["top"].set_visible(False)`) and was in a bit of a rush. Updated to remove top axis as well as made it more like your case.